# View CPU usage of individual processors in UNIX

Tags: unix, cpu-usage

I am trying to diagnose a problem on a server box that I believe is related to CPU usage.

However, when I log in to the box and run 'top' I see a %CPU of 160 or higher.  This is because this is a multi-processor box.

How do I see the CPU usage of the individual processors?

How can I do this in real time?

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. There will be an IT version of SO at some point. In the meantime you may be able to get help with this IT question at one of the sites listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Comment: Actually, I think that this is a perfectly valid question for this environment.  This is at least as valid a question as much of the fluff I see floating through all the time -- not to mention this is helping me solve a programming problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

run "top"

press 1

Comment: If you're using procps top (default on most Linux), that is.  Traditional UNIX top doesn't have this feature.

Comment: The problem with this is when you try to get this information in a log file.

Answer (score 8):

What UNIX are we talking here?

Try `mpstat` if you're in Solaris or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

mpstat -P ALL 5

it will report individual cpu usage every 5 seconds